# Where is \fboxsep (pstricks) defined?

Tags: pstricks

\endpspicture produces an error (for me) because it contains \fboxsep=0pt, and \fboxsep appears not to be undefined.  I thought perhaps I had accidentally deleted the file which contained the definition; so I tried to find where the definition was.  I did a search for \fboxsep in the entire CTAN ...\pstricks\base\   package without finding where it is defined.  What's going on?

EDIT: Various people have reported that it is defined in the LaTex kernel.  I am NOT a LaTex user and until very recently, \pstricks worked fine in PlainTex.  Was it decided that PsTricks is now a LaTex only package, or is it simply a bug in a new version?

Comment: `\fboxsep` is defined in the [LaTeX kernel](https://www.tug.org/svn/texlive/trunk/Master/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/latex.ltx?view=co). But that doesn't answer your question, I'm sure...

Comment: Usually, you would use `\psframebox` with pstricks, and the corresponding length `framesep`. Is `\fboxsep` defined in plain TeX anyway? Could you post a minimal (non-)working code?

Comment: I pointed you to a duplicate question: it is a bug in a new version. However, the newest one (PSTricks' v2.70  2016/09/23) seems to be working OK

Comment: You should update your PSTricks version, at least from http://comedy.dante.de/~herbert/texnik/tex/generic/pstricks/